# PyQt singleShot, using variables values at time of calling?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

In PyQt, I'm trying to set a timer on a certain action based on the values of a variable at the time that I *start* the timer, not the values when it's triggered.

So for example, in code like this:

```
def test(self):
    self.x = 1
    QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.output(self.x))
    self.x = 0

def output(self, text):
    print text
```

It prints `0`, since that's the value of `x` when the `output` function actually runs.  Is there anything I can do to set a one second delay on printing a `1`, the value when the *timer* function itself runs?

Comment: `QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda x=self.x: self.output(x))`.

Comment: Thanks, ekhumoro, but that just prints the method itself: `<built-in method x of Window object at 0x0238B080>`

Comment: What method? In your example, `self.x` is an attribute, not a method. The code I gave is correct, and works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, ekhumoro -- I'm probably using the wrong terminology.  All I can say is that when I paste your code in to replace my line, it doesn't print `1`, it prints a description of the object: `<built-in method x of Window object at 0x0000000002212A68>`.  I appreciate your help, though.

Comment: The `lambda` will simply pass on whatever its default argument set to. In your example code, it will print `1`, because that is what `self.x` is set to. But clearly, you are not running that example code. In the *actual* code you are running, `self.x` has been set to (or is being shadowed by) a method rather than an `int` - and so that is what will be printed. Either way, my code is correct, and works exactly as expected.

Comment: PS: if `Window` is a subclass of `QWidget`,  then `self.x()` will be a method that returns the x coordinate of the widget (relative to its parent, if it has one).